# Robot in infinite 2D Grid, repeats a sequence of moves, is its path intersecting?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, linear-transformations, induction

The problem statement :-
Robot starts at position (0,0) and performs a fixed sequence of operations repeatedly. Each operation in the sequence can be one of the following :-

1. Increment x coordinate (R)
2. Decrement x coordinate (L)
3. Increment y coordinate (U)
4. Decrement y coordinate (D)

i.e. Visit one of the four neighbours.

The robot keeps repeating a fixed sequence of operations indefinitely, does it intersect its own path ?

---

My attempt :-

I have no background in topology or such fields, but I have made a conjecture.

> If the path must intersect itself it must do so within 2 iterations.

I need help in proving this or a counter example of the same.

Here's the progress I've made on proving this :-

- If you use only 3 different operations of the 4 available, then your path must be monotonic in one direction, so the only possibility of intersection is between adjacent iterations. This can be checked by just simulating two iterations.
- If you use only 2 different operations of the 4 available, they may be both along the same axis, in which case you are definitely intersecting within two iterations (in fact in the first iteration itself). In the other case motion is monotonic along both directions, you are not going to intersect anyway.
- One operation is trivial
- The missing piece :- If you use all four operations I need to prove that the robot will definitely intersect in two iterations if it is going to intersect at all.

In fact I think all sequences that use all 4 operations will intersect in within 2 iterations but that is a stronger claim, not needed to prove the conjecture. [Thanks to @ Misha Lavrov's comment below, I now know this is false]

---

Here is a similar question but with a different condition on the paths :- [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512795/robot-on-a-2d-grid-given-series-of-commands-find-if-its-movement-is-restricted).
This question deals with the exact same [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/robot-bounded-in-circle/) that is the motivation behind this new problem I'm trying to solve.

The source problem was to check if the repeated path is bounded, in case it is unbounded, it is allowed to intersect itself. Some of the details about orientation have been removed in this new problem, essentially I'm just trying to deal with the case where the orientation after a sequence of operations is the same as the starting orientation. In all other cases it is a bounded path anyway so it must intersect.

Comment: Not all sequences that use all 4 operations will intersect: consider a sequence that mostly walks right, but does a little dance in the middle where (without intersecting its own path) it uses all the other directions. For example, `R R R U R R D L D R R U R`.

Comment: It took me a while to understand your question. You should make it more clear that there is some fixed sequence of the 4 moves that the robot performs repeatedly, and you are trying to prove that if the first two repetitions of this sequence do not have any intersections, then the robot will never intersect its own path.